# Remove random parts of an object (Chaos Monkey Style)

Tags: javascript, testing

I have a JavaScript object e.g.:

```
const testFixture = {
  a: [
    {b:1},
    {b:2},
    {b:3},
  ],
  b: {c: {d: 44, e: "foo", f: [1,2,3]}}
  c: 3,
  d: false,
  f: "Blah",
}
```

I'd like to have a function I could pass this object to that would mutate it to remove random properties from it, so that I can test whether the thing that uses this object displays an error state, rather than silently erroring.

---

Edit:

To be clear, I mean any deeply nested property. e.g. it might remove `a.b.c.d.e.f[1]` or `a[2].b`

---

Edit 2:

Here's a buggy solution I'm working on based on ideas from Eureka and mkaatman's answers.

It seems to be changing key names to "undefined" which I wasn't expecting. It's also changing numbers to `{}` which I wasn't expecting. Not sure why.

```
var testFixture2 = {
  a: [{
      b: 1, c: 2
    },
    {
      b: 2, c: 2
    },
    {
      b: 3, c: 2, d: "bar"
    },
  ],
  b: {
    c: {
      d: 44,
      e: "foo",
      f: [1, 2, 3]
    }
  },
  c: 3,
  d: false,
  f: "Blah"
};


function getRandomIndex(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function chaosMonkey(thing) {
  if (typeof thing === "object") {
    console.log("object", Object.keys(thing).length, thing);
    const newlyDeformedObject = { ...thing};
    // Make a list of all the keys
    const keys = Object.keys(thing);
    // Choose one at random
    const iKey = getRandomIndex(keys.length);
    let target = newlyDeformedObject[keys[iKey]];
  
    const shouldDelete = getRandomIndex(3) === 0;
    if (shouldDelete) {
      delete target;
      console.log("Object deleted", keys[iKey]);
    } else {
     console.log("+++ Going deeper", thing);
      newlyDeformedObject[keys[iKey]] = chaosMonkey({ ...newlyDeformedObject[keys[iKey]] });
    }
    return newlyDeformedObject;
  } else if (typeof thing === "array") {
    console.log(array);
    const iKey = getRandomIndex(thing.length);
    const shouldDelete = getRandomIndex(3) === 0;
    if (shouldDelete) {
      delete array[iKey];
      console.log("Array deleted", iKey);
    } else {
      array[iKey] = chaosMonkey(array[iKey]);
      return array;
    }
  } else {
    //@todo do something bad based on type e.g. number -> NaN, string -> '', but these are less likely to break something
    delete thing;
    return;
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(chaosMonkey(testFixture2), null, 2));
```

NB: the chances of any object key or array item being recursed into are equal, in order to make modifications equally likely anywhere in the object.

---

Edit 3:

Additional Requirement:

- It MUST always remove at least one thing.

Bonus points for:

1. ways to control the number of things that get deleted
2. any way to limit which properties get deleted or recursed into.
   i.e. allow/deny lists, where:

   - allowRemovalList = properties that it's ok to remove
   - denyRemovalList = properties that it's **not** ok to remove

(It could be that you have some properties that it's ok to remove entirely, but they should not be recursed into and inner parts of them removed.)

NB: Originally I asked for whitelist/blacklist but this caused confusion (and I wouldn't want anyone copying this code to be surprised when they use it) and some answers have implemented it so that blacklist = properties to always remove. I won't penalise any answer for that (and it's trivial to change anyway).

Comment: What specific issue are you having? Seems like a typical recursive function plus a delete, although you'd need to decide how you want to scope the deletions. I'd probably generate a complete list of full object paths and delete at a randomly-chosen one if depth isn't a concern.

Comment: Andreas, that's hilarious! @mkaatman is probably happy to help him though, just for the unusualness of the request.

Comment: Looks like there's a bug in my array detection

Comment: @SamHasler Hi Sam, I've just submitted my solution which uses the slightly more simplistic approach of building an array of all key-value pairs first (recursively) and then removing one of at random. I then run that function in a while loop until all element have been emptied out successfully.

Comment: @SamHasler one other note— it appears you are missing a comma `,` at the end of your `b` key line in the first code block in your question. Please let me know if there is anything else I can do to improve my solution for you. Thanks!

Comment: @SamHasler you can't detect an array with `typeof`. Here's [the list of what it detects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#description). To identify an array, use `Array.isArray(thing)`

Comment: @SamHasler I updated my answer based on your latest requirements https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68133195/remove-random-parts-of-an-object-chaos-monkey-style/68170524#68170524

Comment: @SamHasler is there anything missing in my answer? As far as I can tell, it directly fulfills all of your requirements. If it does not, could you maybe explain in what way it doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

#### Assuming you mean random properties of the root of the object (not properties of properties or properties of array elements)

```js
const testFixture = {
  a: [{
      b: 1
    },
    {
      b: 2
    },
    {
      b: 3
    },
  ],
  b: {
    c: {
      d: 44,
      e: "foo",
      f: [1, 2, 3]
    }
  },

  c: 3,
  d: false,
  f: "Blah",
}

// Make a list of all the keys
const keys = Object.keys(testFixture);
// Choose one at random
const iKey = Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length);
// (For simplicity we are making the assumption that there will always be at least one key)
const deleteKey = keys[iKey]

// Build a new object, that has the all the properties of the old one, except the property selected for deletion.
const out = {};
keys.forEach(key => {
  if (key !== deleteKey) {
    out[key] = testFixture[key]
  }
})

console.log(out)
```

#### Modifying the OP's code, to achieve deep deletion

Great that you have joined in the coding and shown a nearly-complete answer! That is much more likely to engage people's curiosity. I think your code is nearly there: just make sure to do your deletion directly from the target object, otherwise you only delete a temporary variable "target".

Does the below do what you want? (Only one line changed)

```js
var testFixture2 = {
  a: [{
      b: 1,
      c: 2
    },
    {
      b: 2,
      c: 2
    },
    {
      b: 3,
      c: 2,
      d: "bar"
    },
  ],
  b: {
    c: {
      d: 44,
      e: "foo",
      f: [1, 2, 3]
    }
  },
  c: 3,
  d: false,
  f: "Blah"
};


function getRandomIndex(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function chaosMonkey(thing) {
  if (typeof thing === "object") {
    console.log("object", Object.keys(thing).length, thing);
    const newlyDeformedObject = { ...thing
    };
    // Make a list of all the keys
    const keys = Object.keys(thing);
    // Choose one at random
    const iKey = getRandomIndex(keys.length);
    let target = newlyDeformedObject[keys[iKey]];

    const shouldDelete = getRandomIndex(3) === 0;
    if (shouldDelete) {


      // In this line below, we delete the property from "newlyDeformedObject", not just delete the variable "target"

      delete newlyDeformedObject[keys[iKey]];


      console.log("Object deleted", keys[iKey]);
    } else {
      console.log("+++ Going deeper", thing);
      newlyDeformedObject[keys[iKey]] = chaosMonkey({ ...newlyDeformedObject[keys[iKey]]
      });
    }
    return newlyDeformedObject;
  } else if (typeof thing === "array") {
    console.log(array);
    const iKey = getRandomIndex(thing.length);
    const shouldDelete = getRandomIndex(3) === 0;
    if (shouldDelete) {
      delete array[iKey];
      console.log("Array deleted", iKey);
    } else {
      array[iKey] = chaosMonkey(array[iKey]);
      return array;
    }
  } else {
    //@todo do something bad based on type e.g. number -> NaN, string -> '', but these are less likely to break something
    delete thing;
    return;
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(chaosMonkey(testFixture2), null, 2));
```

Comment: By giving them ready-made solutions, you are encouraging the transformation of this site into a free coding service, as Anreas said.

Comment: I think there's value in answering because it's kind of a unique and interesting question even if it's low quality one. I haven't seen someone ask this before and I haven't seen any solution for it.

Comment: @mkaatman, nice answer but I did want deeply nested properties. I've updated the question to reflect this. I expect some recursion will be needed.

Comment: Modify it the way you see fit and then post an updated answer with your solution.

Comment: Well spotted but there's a bigger bug than that in my code:
```{
"a": [
{
"b": 1,
"c": 2
},
{
"b": 2,
"c": 2
},
{
"b": 3,
"c": 2,
"d": "bar"
}
],
"b": {
"c": {
"d": 44,
"e": "foo",
"f": {
"0": 1,
"1": {
"undefined": {
"undefined": {
"undefined": {
"undefined": {
"undefined": {}
}
}
}
}
},
"2": 3
}
}
},
"c": 3,
"d": false,
"e": "Blah"
}
``` 
Ok, so it mangles the data, but a bit too "obviously".

Answer (score 1):

I took a stab at it because I thought the question was interesting and unique. This is a bit sloppy but maybe it's a start if someone else is wondering how to do this in the future.

```js
const testFixture = {
  a: [{
      b: 1
    },
    {
      b: 2
    },
    {
      b: 3
    },
  ],
  b: {
    c: {
      d: 44,
      e: "foo",
      f: [1, 2, 3]
    }
  },
  c: 3,
  d: false,
  f: "Blah"
};


function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function chaosMonkey(object) {
  console.log(Object.keys(testFixture).length, object);
  const newlyDeformedObject = { ...object
  };
  Object.keys(testFixture).forEach((item, index) => {
    const shouldDelete = getRandomInt(2);
    console.log(index, shouldDelete);
    if (shouldDelete) {
      delete newlyDeformedObject[item];
    } else {
      if (typeof newlyDeformedObject[item] === "object") {
        console.log("+++ Going deeper", { ...newlyDeformedObject[item]
        });

        newlyDeformedObject[item] = chaosMonkey({ ...newlyDeformedObject[item]
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return newlyDeformedObject;

}

console.log(chaosMonkey(testFixture));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that features whitelisting and blacklisting, considering blacklisting takes priority over whitelisting:

```js
const testFixture = {
  a: [{ b: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { b: 3 }],
  b: { c: { d: 44, e: "foo", f: [1, 2, 3] } },
  c: 3,
  d: false,
  f: "Blah",
};

const whiteList = [
  ["a", "2", "b"],
  ["b", "c", "e"],
];

const blackList = [
  ["a", "1", "b"],
  ["b", "c", "d"],
];

// Partial match because if a sub-property is whitelisted, the full path has to remain untouched
const isInWhiteList = (input) =>
  whiteList.some((x) =>
    input.reduce((acc, cur, i) => cur === x[i] && acc, true)
  );

// Exact match
const isInBlackList = (input) =>
  blackList.some(
    (x) =>
      x.length === input.length &&
      input.reduce((acc, cur, i) => cur === x[i] && acc, true)
  );

const chaosMonkey = (
  input,
  chanceOfBeingDeleted = 0.2, // Probability of property deletion
  deep = true, // Remove only the deepest properties? If set to false, removes intermediate ones as well
  path = []
) => {
  if (typeof input !== "object") return;

  const propsToDelete = [];
  const itemsDeletedArr = [];

  // Calculate properties to delete
  for (const item in input) {
    const currentPath = [...path, item];
    if (
      (isInBlackList(currentPath) ||
        (!isInWhiteList(currentPath) &&
          Math.random() < chanceOfBeingDeleted)) &&
      (!deep || typeof input[item] !== "object")
    ) {
      propsToDelete.push(item);
    } else {
      const itemsDeleted = chaosMonkey(
        input[item],
        chanceOfBeingDeleted,
        deep,
        currentPath
      );
      itemsDeletedArr.push(itemsDeleted);
    }
  }

  // Delete properties
  if (input instanceof Array) {
    // Delete indexes in reverse direction to prevent indexes shifting
    propsToDelete.reverse().forEach((x) => input.splice(x, 1));
  } else {
    propsToDelete.forEach((x) => delete input[x]);
  }

  // Has deleted at least one property?
  return (
    !!propsToDelete.length ||
    itemsDeletedArr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc || cur, false)
  );
};

// Optionally pass a chance of being deleted as second parameter
while (!chaosMonkey(testFixture)) {
  console.log("chaosMonkey didn't change anything, retrying");
}

console.log(testFixture);
```

Comment: Nice attempt, but unfortunately I've had to add an additional requirement that I guess I assumed was obvious but I understand my explanation was somewhat ambiguous. The solution should always remove at least one thing. I ran yours a few times and sometimes it didn't do anything.

Comment: Can you precise the exact rule? This code removes properties based on a parameterizable probability (20% in the current example). Should I add another rule to remove one random property if nothing has been deleted? Note that the chances of getting an unchanged object are **extremely low** even with a 20% chance of deleting each property. And the blacklisting guarantees that some precise properties are going to be deleted.

Comment: I added a `boolean` return value to verify it and I run a loop to ensure that something is being deleted. I don't verify "something has been deleted while not blacklisted" though

Comment: You're right, it will always delete something, but that appears to be due to the blacklist. If you comment out everything in the blacklist it keeps hitting "chaosMonkey didn't change anything, retrying" and loops infinately.

Comment: Not indefinitely, unless you set 0 as probability

Comment: Sorry, you're right I've run it a million times and it always removes something. Not sure how I got that loop to happen then. I'd also confused myself as I was expecting that whitelist = properties that it's ok to remove, blacklist = properties that it's not ok to remove (so only one would be set). No worries though as I can see how to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer I'm not entirely happy with.  It does randomly remove leaf properties from an object, and it does that fairly well.

But -- and while the question did not specify this, I think it's an interesting possible extension -- this version only removes leaf nodes; it might be preferable to also remove other branches.  While I did think through some possibilities here, nothing really seemed to gel.  It's not a matter of implementation, but of coming up with good requirements.  Do we treat all paths equally?  What does it mean to remove a branch when we want to keep some of its subbranches?  Should we weight the chances of removal higher for leaves than for heavy-weight branches?  And so on.

But, for what this does do, I'm pretty happy with this solution.  It basically converts an object to an array of pairs representing paths to a node and that node's value.  Then we randomly delete some entries from that array and reconstitute an object from the remaining values.

It looks like this:

```js
// utility functions
const pathEntries = (obj) =>
  Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object .entries (obj) .flatMap (
        ([k, x]) => pathEntries (x) .map (([p, v]) => [[Array.isArray(obj) ? Number(k) : k, ... p], v])
      ) 
    : [[[], obj]]

const setPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (v) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? v : Object .assign (
    Array .isArray (o) || Number.isInteger (p) ? [] : {},
    {...o, [p]: setPath (ps) (v) ((o || {}) [p])}
  )

const hydrate = (xs) =>
  xs .reduce ((a, [p, v]) => setPath (p) (v) (a), {})


// helper function
const randomRemove = (xs, count = 1, i = Math .floor (Math .random () * xs .length)) =>
  count <= 0 
    ? [...xs] 
    : randomRemove ([... xs .slice (0, i), ... xs .slice (i + 1)], count - 1)


// main function
const chaosMonkey = (o, count = 1) => 
  hydrate (
    randomRemove (pathEntries (o), count)
  )


// sample data
const testFixture = {a: [{b: 1}, {b: 2}, {b: 3}], b: {c: {d: 44, e: "foo", f: [1, 2, 3]}}, c: 3, d: false, f: "Blah"}


// demo
console .log (chaosMonkey (testFixture, 3))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This is built on three utility functions that I've used often on StackOverflow:

- **[`pathEntries`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20pathEntries)** creates an array of items such as `[['a', 2, 'b'], 3]`, which describes the property `b` of the element with index `2` in the array stored in the `a` property of the root object, and notes that it has value `3`.
- **[`setPath`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20setPath)** takes a path and value like that and a base object and sets the corresponding value along that path, creating new nodes as needed.
- **[`hydrate`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20hydrate)** simply runs `setPath` for each of an array of such entries, building a new minimal object with those values.

We also create a simple helper function **`randomRemove`** which removes random elements from an array.  This is a simple recursion on the number of items to remove, returning the original array if the `count` is zero, otherwise removing one random element and recurring with one less than count.

On top of those, we write our `chaosMonkey` function, that simply calls `pathEntries` on the object, calls `randomRemove` on the result and then `hydrate` to build a new object.

Besides the large question mentioned above, there are two possible changes I imagine we might consider.  Most importantly, this will allow us to remove entries in the middle of our arrays, leaving us with sparse arrays.  We may want to avoid that.  This is a naive fix for that problem:

```js
const chaosMonkey = (o, count = 1) => 
  hydrate (
    randomRemove (pathEntries (o) .filter (xs => !Number .isInteger (xs [xs .length])), count)
  )
```

which avoids removing any array elements at all.  You can see it in this snippet:

```js
// utility functions
const pathEntries = (obj) =>
  Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object .entries (obj) .flatMap (
        ([k, x]) => pathEntries (x) .map (([p, v]) => [[Array.isArray(obj) ? Number(k) : k, ... p], v])
      ) 
    : [[[], obj]]

const setPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (v) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? v : Object .assign (
    Array .isArray (o) || Number.isInteger (p) ? [] : {},
    {...o, [p]: setPath (ps) (v) ((o || {}) [p])}
  )

const hydrate = (xs) =>
  xs .reduce ((a, [p, v]) => setPath (p) (v) (a), {})


// helper function
const randomRemove = (xs, count = 1, i = Math .floor (Math .random () * xs .length)) =>
  count <= 0 ? [...xs] : randomRemove ([... xs .slice (0, i), ... xs .slice (i + 1)], count - 1)


// main function
const chaosMonkey = (o, count = 1) => 
  hydrate (
    randomRemove (pathEntries (o) .filter (xs => !Number .isInteger (xs [xs .length])), count)
  )


// sample data
const testFixture = {a: [{b: 1}, {b: 2}, {b: 3}], b: {c: {d: 44, e: "foo", f: [1, 2, 3]}}, c: 3, d: false, f: "Blah"}


// demo
console .log (chaosMonkey (testFixture, 3))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We might consider a more sophisticated version of this that actually does delete array entries but doesn't leave the holes.  While we could extend this technique to handle that, it might be more effort than it's worth, and perhaps we would instead write a more sophisticated `hydrate`.

Second, this requires us to specify the number of paths to delete.  It seems more in the spirit of the problem to make that number also random, or to consider a fraction of the paths involved, or do something still more interesting.  I think these would mostly be simple variants of the above, and I leave that to the reader.

Comment: I undeleted and completed this answer without looking back at the question and its changes.  It would be almost trivial to add white/blacklists to this technique, I believe.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer. But the question does say that "It could be that you have some properties that it's ok to remove entirely, but they should not be recursed into and inner parts of them removed." (So it seems it's not about just leaf props.)

Comment: @Sherraf: That's what I meant by my comment above.  Those requirements were not there when I wrote my initial approach.  I didn't adjust to handle these new requirements; although I think it would not be difficult to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very different solution that depending on your needs might be a clever one or not very useful.

Javascript can define a [Proxy](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to be the interface between an object and whatever script is using that object. For example:

```js
const obj = { a: 2 }
const proxy = new Proxy(obj, {
  get: () => 3
})
console.log(obj.a) // 2
console.log(proxy.a) // 3
```

So I'm proposing a russian doll of proxies so that every time something tries to access any property of your object, deeply nested or not, there is some likelihood to receive `undefined` instead.

```js
const obj = {
  a: [
    { b: 1 },
    { b: 2 },
    { b: 3 },
  ],
  b: {
    c: {
      d: 44,
      e: "foo",
      f: [1, 2, 3],
    },
  },
  c: 3,
  d: false,
  f: "Blah",
}

function makeRandomlyInaccessible(object, likelihood) {
  const handler = {
    get(target, key, receiver) {
      if (
        key in target
        && Math.random() < likelihood
      ) {
        return undefined
      }
      const result = Reflect.get(target, key, receiver)
      if (typeof result === "object") {
        return new Proxy(result, handler)
      }
      return result
    },
  }

  return new Proxy(object, handler)
}

const monkeyObj = makeRandomlyInaccessible(obj, .1)

console.log(monkeyObj.a[1].b) // 2
console.log(monkeyObj.a[1].b) // 2
console.log(monkeyObj.a[1].b) // undefined
console.log(monkeyObj.a[1].b) // 2
console.log(monkeyObj.a[1].b) // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

The property `get` I'm defining in this proxy is called a "trap". This one traps every call to get a property value. But there are [many other traps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy#handler_functions) you could play with depending on what you need / want to try.

---

If you need the object to be stable (meaning that random properties are missing, but if they are found they are always found, and if they are undefined they are always undefined), you could just memoize the results of the traps like this:

```js
function makeRandomlyInaccessible(object, likelihood) {
  const trapMap = new Map()
  const handler = {
    get(target, key) {
      if (!trapMap.has(target)) {
        trapMap.set(target, {})
      }
      const traps = trapMap.get(target)
      if (key in traps) {
        return traps[key]
      }
      if (
        !(key in traps)
        && Math.random() < likelihood
      ) {
        traps[key] = undefined
        return undefined
      }
      const result = target[key]
      if (typeof result === "object" && result !== null) {
        traps[key] = new Proxy(result, handler)
      } else {
        traps[key] = result
      }
      return traps[key]
    },
  }

  return new Proxy(object, handler)
}
```

Comment: Sneaky! I love the use of proxy. Is there a way of ensuring that it always removes something without setting the likelihood so that it removes a lot of the object? i.e. could you get it to remove a single item?

Comment: @SamHasler I couldn't think of a way to make sure it removes *at least* one. Since in this case, the modifications are made on-the-fly and not through a static analysis of the object beforehand. However, it could be tweaked to force / prevent removal of certain specific properties. I mainly mentioned a Proxy because it's fun to use and it allows for many more things than just static mods of an object (which my other answer focuses on).

Comment: I've been thinking more about this solution and I suspect it's the only one that could ensure it always removes a property that is actually accessed, without needing any allow/denylist, in a way that could balance failures equally over all accessed properties. I'll try to find time to experiment with the code this week and if it works the way I think it will I'll hand out another bonus.

Answer (score 0):

I went for a more simplistic approach. My function builds out a list of all key-value pairs and selects one at random each time it runs. For the sake of this example, I log the name of the removed key each time the function runs along with the stringified object, then run it again, until all keys are successfully removed.

#### Solution #1

```js
const testFixture = {
  a: [{b:1},{b:2},{b:3},],
  b: {c: {d: 44, e: "foo", f: [1,2,3]}},
  c: 3,
  d: false,
  f: "Blah",
};

const chaosMonkey = obj => {
  const getObjKeysPairs = (obj, parent = false) => {
    const objKeysPairs = [];
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      const parentKeyPair = parent ? parent + "." + key : key;
      objKeysPairs.push([obj, key, parentKeyPair]);
      if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
        objKeysPairs.push(...getObjKeysPairs(value, parentKeyPair));
      }
    }
    return objKeysPairs;
  };
  const objKeyPairs = getObjKeysPairs(obj),
        [object, key, path] = objKeyPairs[Math.floor(Math.random() * objKeyPairs.length)];
  console.log("Deleting " + path + " === " + object[key]);
  delete object[key];
};
while (Object.keys(testFixture).length) {
  chaosMonkey(testFixture);
}
console.log("testFixture:", testFixture);
if (Object.keys(testFixture).length === 0) console.log("testFixture emptied successfully");
```

This solution works as-is and deletes keys recursively for both arrays and objects. Using the [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) however, array items are deleted but not entirely removed, leaving an `empty` value remaining.

This does not throw any errors, even silently, because `empty` values are not recognized as valid key-value pairs and therefore are not "re-attempted" as values once deleted initially.

---

**NOTE:** The below explanation is for the first version of this solution. It is still valuable and so I am not removing it, but please see the older version of this solution to see its relevance.

One JS concept worthy of a deeper explanation is this:

```js
if ([Object, Array].includes(value.constructor)) { /* ... */ }
```

Every data type in JavaScript is built upon classes. Up until recently, classes were defined using a functional syntax. ES6+ introduced a new [`class` declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class), which makes creating new classes arguably much easier and essentially decorates the classical syntax.

Each class's constructor can be referenced by its name like a variable (without quotes) or by its name as a string. Here is an example of this:

```js
class CustomObject extends Object {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
const myVar = new CustomObject();
myVar.constructor === CustomObject; // true
myVar.constructor.name === "CustomObject"; // true
```

Another important concept here is the prototypal chain. Every object and type in JavaScript is a prototyped instance of another object, so if you traverse through the prototypal chain you can evaluate any ancestor prototype of any given object, even simple strings or numbers, until you reach the most primitive object which has no prototype and is the ultimate prototype inherited by all types in JavaScript. Here are a few examples of that:

```js
(5).constructor === (5).__proto__?.constructor; // true
(5).__proto__.constructor; // => Number
(5).__proto__.__proto__?.constructor; // => Object
(5).__proto__.__proto__.__proto__?.constructor; // => undefined

"string".constructor === "string".__proto__?.constructor; // true
"string".__proto__.constructor; // => String
"string".__proto__.__proto__?.constructor; // => Object
"string".__proto__.__proto__.__proto__?.constructor; // => undefined

class CustomObject extends Object { constructor() { super(); }}
const myVar = new CustomObject();
myVar.__proto__.constructor; // => CustomObject
myVar.__proto__.__proto__?.constructor; // => Object
myVar.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__?.constructor; // => undefined
```

In your example, this is all very useful for us for the simple purpose of checking whether the value of one of the object's values, regardless of depth, is a nested object or array. Like the examples above, arrays and objects also have unique constructors. The constructor for arrays is `Array` and the constructor for objects is `Object`. I am simply checking to see if the value being evaluated is either one of those types and if so evaluate its own child properties/elements via recursion.

Recursion, if you aren't already familiar with it is the process by which a function calls itself, often passing information allowing the function to reach whatever depth necessary to gather all the information available. This is exactly what we need in your case to build the complete list of all properties in the main object.

Lastly, my purpose in using `[Object, Array].includes(...)` is simply because is a bit easier than using `value.constructor === Object || value.constructor === Array`. Using the [`includes` Array.prototype method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) allows us in this case to check whether the value we are checking, `value.constructor` is equal to either `Object` or `Array`.

There is a spec floating around out there for use of the bitwise OR operator `|` to do something like this so we can write these more naturally like this: `value.constructor === Object | Array`. However, this is purely conceptual at this point and may only work in specific use-cases such as XHTTP requests and fetch.

---

#### Solution #2

In my second solution below, I add an additional check at the end of the function to test whether `object.constructor === Array` and if so, I use the [`splice` Array.prototype method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to completely remove the array element rather than only deleting it, which leaves an `empty` value behind at the deleted index.

If however, you would prefer to remove the array items altogether as the function runs, you can do so using the [`splice` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and simply run the [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) conditionally based on the constructor.

Here is how that would work:

```js
const testFixture = {
  a: [{b:1},{b:2},{b:3},],
  b: {c: {d: 44, e: "foo", f: [1,2,3]}},
  c: 3,
  d: false,
  f: "Blah",
};

const chaosMonkey = obj => {
  const getObjKeysPairs = (obj, parent = false) => {
    const objKeysPairs = [];
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      const parentKeyPair = parent ? parent + "." + key : key;
      objKeysPairs.push([obj, key, parentKeyPair]);
      if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
        objKeysPairs.push(...getObjKeysPairs(value, parentKeyPair));
      }
    }
    return objKeysPairs;
  };
  const objKeyPairs = getObjKeysPairs(obj),
        [object, key, path] = objKeyPairs[Math.floor(Math.random() * objKeyPairs.length)];
  console.log("Deleting " + path + " === " + object[key]);
  delete object[key];
  if (Array.isArray(object)) object.splice(key, 1);
};
while (Object.keys(testFixture).length) {
  chaosMonkey(testFixture);
}
console.log("testFixture:", testFixture);
if (Object.keys(testFixture).length === 0) console.log("testFixture emptied successfully");
```

Comment: Nice solution, like you way you've used it to empty the object. Can you explain the `if ([Object, Array].includes(value.constructor)) {` line?

Comment: @SamHasler certainly. It's a bit deeper of a JS topic, but I tried my best to sum it up concisely and understandably. Please check my updated explanation for an explanation of that. I go a bit deep on data types and the prototypal chain, but if all you are looking for clarification on is why I used the [`Array.includes()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), you can find that at the end of my more lengthy explanations. Let me know if this helps or if I can clarify it further!

Comment: You shouldn't test for array or object like this unless you purposefully want to ignore any custom constructs. The more general test would be `typeof a === 'object && a !== null` for objects, and `Array.isArray(a)` for arrays.

Comment: A common example (even though there are many more), is that to save on RAM some libraries create objects like this: `Object.create(null)` instead of `{}`. These won't have a prototype constructor and yet can hold key-value pairs.

Comment: @Sheraff In most cases, this will work just fine, but if we want to account for those cases such as `Object.create(null)`, it's a quick change as well, but the bulk of the logic remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

This approach allows you to define lists to customize the behavior, where each property is defined as a "path to the property" (for example `"b.c.f[1]"`), as well as the exact `deleteCount`.

- `doNotRemove`: properties specified here *must not* be removed, which implies that all of their parents *must not* be removed either
- `mustRemove`: properties specified here *must* be removed
- `canRemoveButNotModify`: properties specified here *can* be removed, but all of their children *must not* be removed

This approach could easily be tweaked to use a "delete ratio" instead of an absolute count.

---

The basic principle is:

1. we recursively go over the entire object (breadth first) and construct a list of "path to a property", with a JS-like grammar (for example `"b.c.f[1]"`)
2. we match the obtained list with `doNotRemove`, `mustRemove`, and `canRemoveButNotModify` (thanks to a few *very basic* utility functions) to get a list of properties to delete
3. we delete the properties in the list

```js
const obj = {
    a: [
        { b: 1 },
        { b: 2 },
        { b: 3 },
    ],
    b: {
        c: {
            d: 44,
            e: "foo",
            f: [1, 2, 3],
        },
    },
    c: 3,
    d: false,
    f: "Blah",
}

deleteRandomProps(obj, {
    deleteCount: 5,
    doNotRemove: [
        'a[1]',
        'b.c',
    ],
    mustRemove: [
        'a[2]',
        'b.c.e',
    ],
    canRemoveButNotModify: [
        "b.c.f"
    ],

})

console.log('result', obj)

function deleteRandomProps(obj, {
    deleteCount = 0, // number of deletion
    doNotRemove = [], // prevent deletion of property and all its children, of the shape "a[0].b"
    mustRemove = [], // force deletion of property, of the shape "a[0].b"
    canRemoveButNotModify = [], // can delete property entirely but not modify its children, of the shape "a[0].b"
}) {
    // list all possible property paths
    const listOfAllPaths = listPaths(obj)

    // prevent deletion of doNotRemove items
    doNotRemove
        .flatMap(path => allPathsThatLeadToPath(path))
        .forEach(path => {
            // remove all of doNotRemove from full list
            removeItemFromList(path, listOfAllPaths)
            // remove all of doNotRemove from mustRemove
            removeItemFromList(path, mustRemove)
        })

    // prevent deletion of items that are children of canRemoveButNotModify items
    canRemoveButNotModify
        .forEach(path => {
            // remove from full list
            removeChildPaths(path, listOfAllPaths)
            // remove from mustRemove
            removeChildPaths(path, mustRemove)
        })

    // remove from list all properties that are children of a property in mustRemove
    mustRemove.forEach(path => {
        removeItemFromList(path, listOfAllPaths)
        removeChildPaths(path, listOfAllPaths)
    })

    // start from mustRemove and add until deleteCount is reached
    const deletions = [...mustRemove]
    while (deletions.length < deleteCount && listOfAllPaths.length > 0) {
        const path = removeRandomItemFromList(listOfAllPaths)
        // remove from list all properties that are children of the one we're deleting
        removeItemFromList(path, listOfAllPaths)
        removeChildPaths(path, listOfAllPaths)
        // remove from deletions all properties that are children of the new one
        removeItemFromList(path, deletions)
        removeChildPaths(path, deletions)
        deletions.push(path)
    }

    // delete properties from object
    console.log('deleting props', deletions)
    deletions.forEach(path => {
        deleteFromPath(obj, path)
    })

    return obj
}


// create a list of all possible property paths, of the shape "a[0].b"
function listPaths(obj, prefix = '') {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object') {
        return []
    }
    const pureKeys = Object.keys(obj)
    const keys = prefix
        ? pureKeys.map(key => `${prefix}.${key}`)
        : pureKeys
    const values = Object.values(obj)
    const more = []

    values.forEach((value, index) => {
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            value.forEach((item, i) => {
                const newKey = `${keys[index]}[${i}]`
                more.push(newKey)
                more.push(...listPaths(item, newKey))
            })
        } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
            more.push(...listPaths(value, keys[index]))
        }
    })

    return [...keys, ...more]
}

// recursively find property based on list of keys, of the shape ["a", "0", "b"]
function findFromArray(obj, array) {
    if (array.length === 0) {
        return obj
    }
    const [key, ...rest] = array
    if (key in obj) {
        return findFromArray(obj[key], rest)
    }
}

// turn path into list of keys ("a[0].b" => ["a", "0", "b"])
function pathToParticles(path) {
    const regex = /([a-z0-9])/gi
    const particles = path.match(regex)
    return particles || []
}

// deletes a property based on property path, of the shape "a[0].b"
function deleteFromPath(obj, path) {
    const particles = pathToParticles(path)
    const last = particles.pop()
    const lastObject = findFromArray(obj, particles)
    if (lastObject) {
        delete lastObject[last]
    }
}

// turn path into list of path that lead to it ("a[0].b" => ["a", "a[0]", "a[0].b"])
function allPathsThatLeadToPath(path) {
    const regex = /[\[\.]/gi
    const list = [path]
    let match
    while ((match = regex.exec(path)) !== null) {
        list.push(path.substring(0, match.index))
    }
    return list
}

// remove item from an array
function removeItemFromList(item, list) {
    const index = list.indexOf(item)
    if (index !== -1) {
        list.splice(index, 1)
    }
    return list
}

// remove from list all property paths that are children of a property path
// for example "a[0]" will remove "a[0].b", "a[0].b.c", ... but not "a[0]" itself
function removeChildPaths(path, list) {
    for(let i = list.length; i > 0; i--) {
        const item = list[i-1]
        if (item !== path && item.startsWith(path)) {
            list.splice(i-1, 1)
        }
    }
}

// remove a random prop from a list
function removeRandomItemFromList(list) {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)
    const [item] = list.splice(index, 1)
    return item
}
```